# How can I enforce inheritance in my Django models?

Tags: python, django, django-models, flake8

In my Django app, I have an abstract model called `MyModel` that has e.g. `created_at` and `updated_at` fields. I want all the models in my project to subclass `MyModel` rather than using `django.db.models.Model` directly.

We have several developers on our app, so I want to use some sort of linter or CI check to enforce that this happens. How can I do this?

Comment: You can [create your own flake8 plugin](https://towardsdev.com/how-to-create-a-flake-8-plugin-6bda6b7406e9)

Comment: You can write your own Django validation plugin to validate this.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem do you mean a custom flake8 plugin?

Comment: @tao_oat: no, Django has had a lot of focus on validation. For example validating that `choices=...` in a `CharField` indeed is a 2-tuple of options, etc. So you can use Django's mechanism to let it report such error/warning when you *start* the Django server, or do anything else like making migrations, etc.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thank you! Do you perhaps have a link to some documentation on such plugins? A Google search for "django validation plugin" returns no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by [Willem Van Onsem in their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73443788/how-can-i-enforce-inheritance-in-my-django-models?noredirect=1#comment129698707_73443788) you can write your own checks using the [System check framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/checks/).

Assuming we have the following models in an app named "checktest" with `Parent` being the model that all models should inherit from:

```
from django.db import models


class Parent(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True


# This should raise an error
class Foo(models.Model):
    pass


# This should be fine
class Bar(Parent):
    pass
```

We'll write a check as follows in a file `checktest/custom_checks.py`, note that the list `APPS_TO_TEST` contains the names of the apps whose models should inherit from the parent class:

```
from django.apps import apps
from django.core.checks import Error, register, Tags
from .models import Parent

# List of apps that should inherit from Parent
APPS_TO_TEST = ["checktest"]


@register(Tags.models)
def model_must_inherit(app_configs, **kwargs):
    errors = []
    for app in APPS_TO_TEST:
        models = apps.get_app_config(app).get_models()
        for model in models:
            if not issubclass(model, Parent):
                errors.append(Error(
                    f"Model {model.__name__} does not inherit from Parent",
                    hint="Models must inherit from the Parent class",
                    obj=model,
                    id="checktest.E001"
                ))
    return errors
```

In the app configs `ready` method we'll import the above file so that the check will get run:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ChecktestConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'checktest'

    def ready(self) -> None:
        from . import custom_checks
```

Now whenever we run commands like `runserver` or `migrate` the checks will get implicitly run. In a CI environment you can explicitly run the checks using the [check](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/django-admin/#check) command.